# Is it possible to do a for loop while an Int is in a certain range in swift?

Tags: for-loop, swift, range

Is it possible to do a regular for loop while an Int is in a certain range in swift?

this is kinda what I want to achieve:

```
func someFunc(var plusOrMinus:Int) {

    for var i:Int = 0; i == -8...8;i += plusOrMinus {

 }
}
```

or:

```
func someFunc(var plusOrMinus:Int) {

    for var i:Int = 0; i in -8...8;i += plusOrMinus {

 }
}
```

or:

```
func someFunc(var plusOrMinus:Int) {

    for var i:Int = 0; i == <-8,8>;i += plusOrMinus {

 }
}
```

None of these work. Hope you understand the question and can help me. :)

Comment: The Swift equivalent to `i in -8...8` would be the pattern matching operator with a range, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893110/can-i-use-the-range-operator-with-if-statement-in-swift.

Comment: Not really an appropriate use of pattern matching or ranges.  ClosedInterval is what’s wanted here (or stride), see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if an `Int` is in the range `-8...8` you can just check both ends of the range with a conditional and combine them with `&&`:

```
func someFunc(var plusOrMinus:Int) {

    for var i = 0; i >= -8 && i <= 8; i += plusOrMinus {
        println(i) 
    }
}
```

Note:  Swift can infer the type `Int` so you don't have to assign it explicitly.

From @MartinR's comment, you could use the pattern-match operator `~=` to check if `i` is in the range, but the method above is more straightforward and likely more efficient.

```
func someFunc(var plusOrMinus:Int) {

    for var i = 0; -8...8 ~= i; i += plusOrMinus {
        println(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: HAHA , thank you, I did this with out the = in <= and >= previously, but that did not work... Of course I now understand why :D

Comment: Using `~=` and `Range` should be just as efficient as the `&&` since it’ll cause `...` to return a `ClosedInterval`, but it’s kind of abusing the `~=` IMO, better to create the `ClosedInterval` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use for…in rather than a C-style loop, you could use `stride`, but check which direction you’re going in to determine whether you want a target that’s less than or more than the initial value:

```
func someFunc(plusOrMinus: Int) {
    precondition(plusOrMinus != 0)
    let target = plusOrMinus > 0 ? 8 : -8

    for i in stride(from: 0, through: target, by: plusOrMinus) {
        println(i)
    }
}
```

The `-8...8` range you were going for is possible, but you have to explicitly create a closed interval and then check your counter is within it:

```
func someFunc(plusOrMinus: Int) {
    let interval = -8...8 as ClosedInterval
    for var i = 0; interval.contains(i); i += plusOrMinus {
        println(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: ah yes that is nicer – though you’re reliant on the optimizer eliminating the creation of multiple `ClosedIntervals` for each iteration of the loop.