# if integer is greater than x but less than y (Swift)

Tags: swift, if-statement, integer, range

I was wondering if there is any smooth way of checking the value of an integer in a range in swift.

I have an integer that can be any number between 0 and 1000

I want to write an if statement for "if the integer is between 300 and 700 - do this and if its any other number - do something else"

I could write:

```
if integer > 300 {
    if integer < 700 {
      //do something else1
    }
    //do something
} else {
    // do something else2

}
```

But I want to minimize the amount of code to write since "do something else1" and "do something else2" are supposed to be the same

It doesn't seem that you can write :

```
if 300 < integer < 700 {

} else {

}
```

I tried using

```
if integer == 300..<700 {
}
```

but that didn't work either. Anybody got a suggestion?

Comment: You should really read the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID76

Comment: *"I tried using "if integer == 300..<700"* – The given answer shows the straight forward solution, but something like that *is* possible, compare [Can I use the range operator with if statement in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893110/can-i-use-the-range-operator-with-if-statement-in-swift).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! So the shortest way is to use if 300 ... 700 ~= integer { // do something } else { // do something else }

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
if integer > 300 && integer < 700 {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else               
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, that does work! I thought there might have been an even shorter way of writing it without repeating with && and "integer" but this might be the best way. Thank you

Comment: Actually I did find a shorter way that Martin R pointed to 

You can write:

if 300 ... 700 ~= integer {
}

Comment: William +1 but use the half open operator!

Answer (score 10):

There is a type, `HalfOpenInterval`, that can be constructed with `...` and that has a `.contains` method:

```
if (301..<700).contains(integer) {
    // etc.
}
```

Note, `301..<700` on its own will create a `Range`, which doesn’t have a contains function, but Swift’s type inference will see that you’re calling a method that only `HalfOpenInterval` has, and so picks that particular overload.

I mention this just because if you want to store the interval as a variable instead of using it in-line, you need to specify:

```
let interval = 301..<700 as HalfOpenInterval
if interval.contains(integer) {
  // etc.
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, with Xcode 6.3 in optimized mode, this also gives the same "optimal" assembly code as `if integer > 300 && integer < 700` or `if 300 ... 700 ~= integer` which I just added to http://stackoverflow.com/a/24893494/1187415.

Comment: Yeah apparently all the standard library code can be inlined (and the swift compiler is very keen to inline with -O)

Comment: And as Willian Larson points out, the contains operator can be used for shorter syntax, in `if 300..<700 ~= integer {`

Comment: I’m not sure that’s really the intended use of the `~=` operator, I see that more as the underlying mechanism for switch rather than something supposed to be used stand-alone.  `.contains` signals intent more clearly IMHO.