# Swift 2 - Pattern matching in "if"

Tags: swift, if-statement, syntax, pattern-matching, swift2

Recently I've saw the WWDC 2015 keynote from Apple. I also looked at some documentation but I can't find a "pattern matching in if" section, how it was written on one of the slides which they have shown.
(68min 00sec video from [Apple Events](http://www.apple.com/live/2015-june-event/))

Do you know what's this refers to? Or the syntax?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

All it really means is that if statements now support pattern matching like switch statements already have. For example, the following is now a valid way of using if/else if/else statements to "switch" over the cases of an enum.

```
enum TestEnum {
    case One
    case Two
    case Three
}

let state = TestEnum.Three

if case .One = state {
    print("1")
} else if case .Two = state {
    print("2")
} else {
    print("3")
}
```

And the following is now an acceptable way of checking if `someInteger` is within a given range.

```
let someInteger = 42
if case 0...100 = someInteger {
    // ...
}
```

Here are a couple more examples using the optional pattern from [The Swift Programming Language](https://itun.es/us/k5SW7.l)

```
let someOptional: Int? = 42
// Match using an enumeration case pattern
if case .Some(let x) = someOptional {
    print(x)
}

// Match using an optional pattern
if case let x? = someOptional {
    print(x)
}
```

Comment: And the last two statements are – if I understand it correctly – equivalent to the well-known `if let x = someOptional { }`.

Comment: That's an exciting prospect, I've been waiting for that since Swift came out.

Comment: @MartinR yeah they are, which can make you wondering why the optional pattern may be useful instead of using the `if let x = someOptional` optional binding syntax. In fact that's not very useful when used in simple `if` statements like here, but more useful with `for` or `while` loops (like `for case let x? in arrayOfOptionalInts` which only loops on non-nil values in the array), or for more complex `if` statements like `if case let (x?, y?) in someFuncThatReturnsATupleOfOptionals()` which will only be true if both elements in the tuple are non-nil and then bind both x and y at the same time.

Comment: This is, however, the worse syntax I have ever seen. Ever. Single equals sign on a test? A case statement in there too? Why isn't this just the `in` operator?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Just one `=` as `==` checks for equality and `is equal` is not the same as `matches pattern`. Equality would mean `is equal to pattern` e.g. when you compare *two patterns*.  But I fail to see the point of adding case as there is a pattern match in swift already (even in Swift 1.x): `if case 0...100 = someInteger` can also be written as `if 0...100 ~= someInteger` as `~=` kinda is the pattern match operator (a bit like `=~` in Perl) and it can even be overloaded for custom types.

Comment: in your enumeration case ... is it actually 2 lines? ie does it mean loop through both cases Some and None—which obviously the None won't go into the code block?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Adding onto @Mecki's explanation, this syntax uses a single `=` because there is actually a (hypothetical) assignment here (though sometimes the assigned-to “variable” is discarded). `if case let x? = someOptional` can be read as _“if the assignment of `someOptional` to `let x: Wrapped` is possible”_; and `if case .One = state` can be read as _“if the assignment of `someInteger` to a discarded `let _` where `_` matches pattern `.One` is possible”_. TL;DR— this syntax is exactly the same as what you can use for pattern matching & `let «varname»` captures in Swift's `switch`es.