# How case works in if-case

Tags: swift

An old C programmer could use some help with Swift.

I don't understanding something about the if-case syntax. E.g.:

```
if case 20...30 = age {
   print ("in range.")
}
```

The `case 20...30 = age` appears to be the conditional test for the `if` statement. So I was initially confused to see the assignment operator ('=') used instead of a comparison operator ('==').

Ok, I thought to myself, that probably means the `case` statement is actually a function call that returns a boolean value. The returned value will then satisfy the comparison test in the `if` statement.

As an experiment, I tried treating the the `case` statement like a regular conditional test and placed parentheses around it. Swift will happily accept `if (x == 5)` or `if (true)`. But `if (case 20...30 = age)` generates an error. So the `case` statement doesn't seem to behave like function.

I'm just curious to understand what's happening here. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720289/swift-2-pattern-matching-in-if, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893110/can-i-use-the-range-operator-with-if-statement-in-swift.

Comment: If you feel your question have been answered, please vote and accept and answer.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The operator is `if case`, so you can't put parentheses. The syntax and behavior are based on those of the `case` statement in a Swift `switch` statement (see [my online book](http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_switch_statement) if you need details). In a `case` statement, `20...30` is an interval, used as a *pattern*, which operates by using `contains` against the interval. The equals sign is indeed truly confusing, but that was their first attempt at a syntax for expressing what the `case` statement should be comparing with (i.e. the *tag* that comes after the `switch` keyword in a `switch` statement).

So, if you understand this:

```
switch age {
case 20...30:
    // do stuff
default:break
}
```

... then you understand how it is morphed directly into this:

```
if case 20...30 = age {
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: That's helpful, thank you. I can see how the `if case` evolved from the `switch case`, but I'm glad to know that others also find the use of an equals sign in the syntax to be confusing.

Comment: I believe the syntax will change in the future.

Comment: This is even more confusing when the two sides can be swapped - like how `if myBool == true {...` is equivalent to `if case myBool = true {...` (note that `myBool` is an already defined constant before this code) . This swapping is valid in some situations (like bools, enums with no associated values), but causes compile errors in other situations (like enums with associated values, ranges (as the original question)).

Comment: " In a case statement, 20...30 is an interval, used as a pattern, which operates by using contains against the interval." I think this is incorrect. Ultimately `contains` is called, by the direct call is to `~=`, which is generalized to all kinds of pattern matching

Comment: @Alexander Yeah but for a range `~=` means `contains`. That is exactly what "used as a pattern, which operates by using `contains`" is intended to mean (or conceal).

Answer (score 10):

@matt does a good job of explaining what that code does. I'm here to suggest a better alternative.

You can use the [`~=`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/operator/tildeeq/#comment-func-tildeeq-i_-intervaltype_-i-value_-i-bound) operator to check ranges. It's a regular operator/function that just returns a `Bool`, with no special language magic.

```
if 20...30 ~= age {
   print ("in range.")
}
```

Comment: Why is `if 20...30 ~= age` "less special language magic" (whatever that means) or "better" than `if case 20...30 = age` ?

Comment: 1) The `if case` syntax is confusing (or else this question wouldn't exist). 2) The `~=` is a regular function, anyone who didn't know it could command click it and see the implementation, just like they would any other foreign function.

Comment: If we're going for clearer alternatives, I would also suggest `if (20...30).contains(age) {...}` seeing as the header for the pattern matching operator actually doesn't say exactly what it does.

Comment: @originaluser2 Fair point, though I've seen `~=` to be quite common. Seems like a nice middle ground between verbosity and magic

Comment: If you want "no special language magic", why are you using Swift?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei Oh interesting. Xcode supports jump to declaration for C++ operators, but not Swift's :/

Comment: @Alexander it did in Xcode 8.x, but when they rewrote the editor for Xcode 9.x, they didn't add that functionality back in. I filed a radar on 2017-07-11 and have received no response. Since it was not closed, I suspect they're working on re-implementing it.

Comment: @BenLeggiero Ahaha, I thought I was going crazy. I could have sworn I have `⌘` clicked it before!

Answer (score 2):

Just another note about these Swift operators. One must remember that Swift has a very advanced and abstracted compiler, so keywords are just keywords, and their behavior depends on their usage.
Unlike C (and other syntactically related languages from C++ to JavaScript), where `if` is simply used to test a Boolean value (or something that can be converted to one), in Swift, the concept of the `if` statement is much more broad. **I generally think of it gating access to a scope by using a variety of techniques, including Boolean tests.**

You can think of `if`, `guard`, `while`, and `repeat`-`while` as more general control flow statements, with much more advanced behavior. Certainly they can still test a Boolean value, but they can also test other conditions as well. In your scenario, the condition being tested is whether some variable matches a defined pattern (does `age` match the pattern `20...30`).

You can also test whether a variable was successfully set to a non-`nil` value (`if let`). The result of the `let` operation doesn't ever return a Boolean, but since it occurs within the `if` statement, the Swift runtime knows that it's part of the control flow. Also note that this slightly changes the behavior of `let`, insofar as any code inside the `if` block now sees the new non-`nil` value and is assured it's not `nil`.

These behaviors can also be combined with commas, like this:

```
if !skipAgeTest,                 // `if` tests a Boolean
    let age = Double(ageString), // `if` tests optional assignment
    case 20...30 = age           // `if` tests pattern matching
    {
    // `age` variable exists and is not `nil` and is between `20` and `30`, inclusive
}
```

so the concept of `if let` or `if case` being separate operators is... not exactly thinking about it in the right way.

And like I said, this syntax is also valid in other control flows:

```
while !skipAgeTest,
    let age = Double(ageString),
    case 20...30 = age {
    // `age` is validated
    // Probably also change `ageString` while we're in here
}


guard !skipAgeTest,
    let age = Double(ageString),
    case 20...30 = age
    else {
    // `age` is invalid, and not available in this block
}
// `age` is valid
```

Comment: "The result of the let operation doesn't ever return a Boolean" -- I would beg to differ.  The boolean is if the let is successful.  The let itself assigns the value if it can, and "returns" a boolean to the "if" if it was successful or not.

Comment: @chadbag I recommend you hang out in the compiler engineer circles if you're interested how things like this work. The current compiler implementation is at https://GitHub.com/apple/swift; feel free to look through. As far as I can tell, `if let` is handled separately as its own expression, and assignment never returns any value, which is why all attempts to get a value out of it result in a compile-time error. Either way, thinking of it like you do is not useful when programming in Swift

Answer (score 2):

## Range Containment

Use the [~=](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/operator/tildeeq/#comment-func-tildeeq-i_-intervaltype_-i-value_-i-bound) operator, as @Alexander mentioned.

```
 if (1...10).contains(n) {
     print("pass")
 }

 switch n {
     case 1...10: print("pass")
     default: print("bug")
 }

 if case 1...10 = n {
     print("pass")
 }

 if 1...10 ~= n {
     print("pass")
 }
```

You can even do Ranges of Characters:

```
 if "a"..."z" ~= "a" {
     print("pass")
 }
```

---

## Overloading ~=

I made a couple overloads, so that you can not only check for Range, but also Arrays and Sets

```
func ~=<T: Equatable> (pattern: [T], value: T) -> Bool { return pattern.contains(value) }
func ~=<T: Equatable> (pattern: Set<T>, value: T) -> Bool { return pattern.contains(value) }
func ~=<T: Equatable> (pattern: Set<T>, value: Set<T>) -> Bool { return pattern.union(value).count < pattern.count + value.count }
```

Which allows you to do this:

```
if [1, 2, 3] ~= 2 {
    print("pass")
}

if [1, 2, 3] ~= [3, 4, 5] {
    print("pass")
}
```

---

## Tuples

However, when using tuples, you'll still have to use **if case**

```
 if case (1...10, 1...10) = (number1, number1) {
     print("0")
 }
```

You can even do the `_` syntactic sugar

```
 if case (1...10, _) = (number1, number1) {
     print("0")
 }
```

---

## Optionals

```
 if case .some = Optional(number) {
     print("pass")
 }

 if case .some(let x) = Optional(number) {
     print(x)
 }

 if case let x? = Optional(number) {
     print(x)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the correct answer has already been given, still there is one option left:

`20...30` is a **ClosedRange** and has a built-in method which is more readable that can do work for you: `contains`

```
if (20...30).contains(age) {
   print ("in range.")
}
```