# How works "guard case let" for non-enums

Tags: swift

Please, can anyone explain why this works?

```
func howMany() -> Int {return 11}
guard case let output = howMany(), output > 10 else {return}
```

I understand how *guard/if/while/for case let* works with enums. Pattern matching is great. But here is no enum and this works too. What is the language construct that allows that?

*(This example was taken from Matt Neuburg's book.)*

Comment: In your case, `output` in an [identifier pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html), which always succeeds. `switch` doesn't require a value to be an enum.

Comment: Silly example, there's absolutely no reason to write this over `guard howMany() < 10 else { return }`

Comment: There is at least one reason (except educational purposes): **output** variable remains in scope after guard and can be used.

Answer (score 3):

It's the `if case` construct. (`guard` is merely a negative `if`, if you see what I mean.)

The whole idea of this construct is that it lets you use an ordinary `if` or `guard` while taking advantage of switch case pattern matching. A major use is to do extraction of an associated value from an enum without the heavyweight `switch` construct, but you can use it anywhere that pattern matching in a condition makes sense (as here).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/37888514/341994

Comment: Look for "if case" in the Index (or see p. 261 if you have the latest edition).

Comment: Thanks, Matt! :) Now much clearer, as this works too: `switch howMany() {
case let output: print("howMany:\(output)")
}`

Comment: Exactly. The thing after the `=` in the `if case` would be the "tag" in the `switch` statement.