# Swift/SwiftUI: If case in one line, is it possible?

Tags: swift, swiftui

`If case` in one line, is it possible?

Example:

```
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

let str = if case .dark == colorScheme ? "dark" : "light"
```

[Think question similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888376/how-case-works-in-if-case)

Comment: `let str = colorScheme == .dark ? "dark" : "light"`

Answer (score 1):

`case` + `=` is just a different spelling enabled by having `~=` defined.

```swift
if case 1... = 2 // true!
```

```swift
if 1... ~= 2 // Same as above.
```

So, you *could* write

```swift
let str = .dark ~= colorScheme ? "dark" : "light"
```

[But all that does is call `==`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Policy.swift)…

```swift
public func ~= <T: Equatable>(a: T, b: T) -> Bool {
  return a == b
}
```

…so you should just write it more clearly, as suggested by the comments:

```swift
let str = colorScheme == .dark ? "dark" : "light"
```

Also, never name anything `str`. That practice is a holdover from a time when variable name length mattered.