# How can you do a simple inline test for an enumeration's case that has associated values you don't care about?

Tags: swift, enums, swift4, associated-value

Given this code:

```
class Item{}

func foo(item:Item){}

enum SelectionType{
    case single(resultsHandler:(Item)->Void)
    case multi(resultsHandler:([Item])->Void)
}

var selectionType:SelectionType = .single(resultsHandler:foo)

// This line won't compile
let title = (selectionType == .single)
    ? "Choose an item"
    : "Choose items"
```

How can you update the part that won't compile?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720289/swift-2-pattern-matching-in-if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ternary operator cannot work for enums with associated values, because the classic equality operator does not work with them. You have to use pattern matching, or `if case` syntax:

```
let title: String
if case .single = selectionType {
    title = "Choose an item"
} else {
    title = "Choose items"
}
```

Comment: Ugh! That's what I was afraid of.  Leaving it open a little longer for other ways to solve this. I'm thinking maybe an extension or similar. Lots to try.  If nothing comes up that's a viable alternative, I'll mark yours as the accepted answer.

Comment: The wildcard pattern is not needed: `if case let .single = selectionType`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a direct way to address what you are looking for.

## My understanding:

- Enums are not equatable by default, you have to implement Equatable
- For enums with associated values, even if you implemented it, I don't think it is possible to achieve what you had asked.

## Computed variable (Workaround 1):

```
enum SelectionType{

    case single(resultsHandler:(Item)->Void)
    case multi(resultsHandler:([Item])->Void)

    var title : String {

        let text : String

        switch self {

        case .single(_):
            text = "Choose an item"
        case .multi(_):
            text = "Choose items"
        }

        return text
    }
}

var title = selectionType.title
```

## Use if case (Workaround 2):

```
if case .single(_) = selectionType {
    print("Choose an item")
}
else {
    print("Choose items")
}
```