# Is there a way to use wildcard (_) pattern in swift's if statement?

Tags: swift

```
let somePoint = (1, 1)
switch somePoint {
case (0, 0):
    print("\(somePoint) is at the origin")
case (_, 0):
    print("\(somePoint) is on the x-axis")
case (0, _):
    print("\(somePoint) is on the y-axis")
case (-2...2, -2...2):
    print("\(somePoint) is inside the box")
default:
    print("\(somePoint) is outside of the box")
}
// Prints "(1, 1) is inside the box"

//using while loop to replicate the code above
    let somePoint = (1, 1)
var find = true
    while(find){
        if ((0, 0) == somePoint){
            print("\(somePoint) is at the origin")
            find = false
        }
        else if ((_, 0) == somePoint){ //encountered error
            print("\(somePoint) is on the x-axis")
            find = false
        }

}
```

Hello I'm new to swift and there's still a lot of stuff I don't know yet. I'm reading the swift's documentation on control flow and came across switch statement, from the code above as you can see I was able to use (*,0) and (-2...2, -2...2) to compare with (1,1) using switch statement but was unable to do the same using if. For example, compare (**,0) == (1,1) gave me this error: "   '***' can only appear in a pattern or on the left side of an assignment   ". So my question is, is there a way I can replicate the switch statement above with the wildcard pattern (_) using while loop and if statement instead? I try doing if (Any, 0) but that also gave me an error. -Thank You

Comment: The problem is not in the if statement but in the `==` function. How would you check for equality two objects if one of the "arguments" is missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30722805/1187415

Comment: Interesting... switch statement compare one value with another differently than that of ==. I was hoping I was able to do if((_, 0)  == (1,0)) that this condition would be correct as well since in switch the _ means any value but thanks!

Comment: That's an interesting observation but wait till you get to enums with associated values!

Comment: As explained in the above-referenced answer you can do pattern matching in if statements. In your case that would  be `if case (_, 0) = somePoint { }` or `if case (-2...2, -2...2) = somePoint { }`, compare also https://stackoverflow.com/a/24893494/1187415.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs earlier than if statement to be precise:

`let problematicPoint = (_, 0) // this will show an error`

So when you trying to compare it to `somePoint` it's already ambiguous. To understand the core of the issue you need to understand what's tuple type is Swift.

> All tuple types contain two or more types, except for Void which is a
>   type alias for the empty tuple type, ().

So if for some reason you still want to do that thing and kinda "omit" one of the tuple types, you can use optionals:

```swift
let somePoint: (x: Int?, y: Int) = (1, 1)

if (0, 0) == somePoint {
  // do something
} else if (nil, 0) == somePoint {
  // do something
}
```

But generally I would simply go for an `Equatable` `struct` or `enum` and compare those than using tuples in more complex cases.