# How to quickly check if an Integer lies within a given range

Tags: swift

I have an integer `x` and I want to check if it lies between a given boundary / within a given range.

The straightforward approach would be

```
let contains = x > lowerBounds && x < higherBounds
```

Is there a more swifty approach to this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can create a range and check if it contains `x`:

```
let contains = (lowerBounds...upperBounds).contains(x)
```

e.g.:

```
let successful = (200..<300).contains(httpStatusCode)
```

Comment: I'm getting "Binary operator '..<' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' operands" error 

Comment: @MohitGarg Did you try that operation with two non-optional values? Otherwise you need to unwrap those values first.

Comment: Thanks, this method even faster than ~= or if >= && <=  (faster I mean if large amount of data we need to compare*)

Comment: @user1195202 can you share how you did you manage to come to that conclusion? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46561616/321629

Answer (score 35):

Or you can use the pattern matching operator:

```
let contains = lowerBounds...uppperBounds ~= x
```