# Can I use the range operator in a guard statement in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to figure out an alternate way to do something like this, using the range operator.

```
guard let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode, statusCode >= 200 && statusCode <= 299 else {return}
```

Maybe something like this:

```
guard let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode where (200...299).contains(statusCode) else {return}
```

or

```
guard let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode, statusCode case 200...299 else {return}
```

Is this possible in Swift?

Comment: nice question !

Comment: Related: [Can I use the range operator with if statement in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893110/can-i-use-the-range-operator-with-if-statement-in-swift)

Comment: The pattern matching of ranges in switch statements is defined by the `~=` operator. It's a really cool feature, because it means that any matching you can do in a switch statement, you can do manually with `~=`. It also means you can extend the capabilities of switch statements by implementing custom `~=` operator functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you like:

```
guard
    let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode,
    (200...299).contains(statusCode) else {return}
```

or:

```
guard
    let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode,
    case 200...299 = statusCode else {return}
```

or:

```
guard
    let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode,
    200...299 ~= statusCode else {return}
```

Comment: Thanks! Interesting that everyone who replied has put the guard statement on a separate line. Is this a convention? I haven't seen it before.

Comment: @KeithGrout, I do not know if this is a popular convention or not. But putting line break after the keyword `guard` makes it clear that it has multiple conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possibile solution

```
guard
    let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode,
    200...299 ~= statusCode
    else { return }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for a different solution, you can also use:

```
guard
    let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode,
    statusCode / 100 == 2
else {
    return
}
```