# Can I create a numeric type restricted to certain values in Swift?

Tags: swift, types, range

I'm wondering if there's a way to specify a numeric type constrained to say a Range or ClosedRange of values.

Non-compiling examples:

```
typealias QuarterNumber = 1...4
typealias VolumeLevel = 0...11
typealias ObtuseAngle = 90.0<..<180.0
```

Now for the first example I might instead create something like:

```
enum QuarterNumber : Int {
   case First = 1
   case Second = 2
   case Third = 3 
   case Fourth = 4
}
```

However, that becomes unwieldy in the `VolumeLevel` case where I'd definitely want to just use the raw numbers. And in the `ObtuseAngle` case it's completely impractical to specify all the individual values it could take.

Answer (score 2):

One way I might do this is with a wrapper type:

```
struct ObtuseAngle {
    var value: Double
}

extension ObtuseAngle : ExpressibleByFloatLiteral, ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
  init(floatLiteral v: FloatLiteralType) {
    guard 90.0 < v && v < 180.0 else {
      preconditionFailure("Invalid angle")
    }
    self.init(value: v)
  }
  init(integerLiteral v: IntegerLiteralType) {
    self.init(floatLiteral: Double(v))
  }
}

let x: ObtuseAngle = 115    // works
let y: ObtuseAngle = 45     // runtime crash
```

The downside is that now the actual value is buried in `.value` instead of being a more "primitive" type. I also lose all the mathematical operators I would have on the "base" type, but that makes some sense because e.g. two obtuse angles may not be obtuse when added, and multiplying them would not really result in an angle type, etc.

Note in this example it might also be appropriate to declare value with type `Measurement<UnitAngle>` and initialize it to `Measurement(value: v, unit: UnitAngle.degrees)`.

Comment: `v > 90.0 && v < 180.0` is better written as `90 < v && v < 180`, and even better as `(90...180).contains(v)`

Comment: @Alexander `(91..<180).contains(v)`

Comment: @Alexander: `(90...180).contains(v)` is *far slower* than `90 < v && v < 180`, probably it traverses the array until a match is found.

Comment: I can't see the point of this at all. If you're after a run-time error, a simple solution like 

`extension Numeric { var obtuse: Double { your condition followed by run-time error }` would do. 
Only difference would be instead of `let x: ObtuseAngle = 45`, `let x = 45.obtuse`.

Comment: @MartinR That can't be, because there's no array being made. Have you tried a release build?

Comment: @Alexander: Yes, I did. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/46561616/1187415 – But "traverses the array" should be "traverses the collection"

Comment: Other threads here (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24893494/179583) claim that pattern matching generates optimal assembly but in this case neither `90...180 ~= v` nor `91..<180 ~= v` would correctly match angles strictly between 90 and 180. I did clean up to put the value in the middle of the range.

Comment: @MartinR That ... sounds crazy. Why is no specialized definition for floats/doubles?

Comment: The only thing I'd add is using a failable initializer!

Comment: @Alexander: Well – I am not sure anymore. When running the benchmarks repeatedly, there is no significant difference anymore. Perhaps I made some error initially. – Also I deleted my last comment, `contains` does work with a range of doubles.

Comment: @fpg1503 That's a good suggestion, but using a failable initializer means it won't be literal expressible. In practice that may/may not be an okay tradeoff depending on usage.

Comment: @natevw I’d rather have type safety and non crashable code than this convenience but surely it’s not always as simple as that

Comment: @fpg1503 Even if it was a failable initializer, what could you possibly do to handle the failure at runtime?