# How to check if an Int in a constant, matches an Int in a CountableClosedRange<Int>

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to programming. Self teaching so I wanted to ask the internet for help.

I wanted to see if an Int I stored in a constant, matches a single digit in a CountableClosedRange, and if so, spit out the boolean value true. See below:

```
let physics = 76
let math = 79
let history = 94
let language = 98


let aPlus = [95...100]

let didPhysicsGetA = physics == aPlus
```

76 is obviously not in that range, so in this case I'd want didPhysicsGetA to comeback as false.

How can I do so, and are there better ways?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893110/can-i-use-the-range-operator-with-if-statement-in-swift

Answer (score 5):

`[]` denotes an array. You just want a range, not an array of ranges, so you should remove the `[]`:

```
let aPlus = 95...100
```

To check if a number is in a range, you can either use the `~=` pattern matching operator,

```
aPlus ~= physics
```

or call `contains`:

```
aPlus.contains(physics)
```

You should choose whichever is the most readable to you.

Comment: Your pattern matching is reversed.  It should be aPlus ~= physics.  Otherwise you get a error "Cannot convert value of type..."

Comment: @P.Stern Oh gosh. What was I doing 2 years ago! 

Answer (score 4):

First of all `[95...100]` will result in `[CountableClosedRange<Int>]` means array of `CountableClosedRange<Int>`. So what you need is `(95...100)`.

```
let aPlus = (95...100) // or you can even emit the brackets 95...100
```

Now to check `Int` is in this `aPlus` range you can use **pattern match** operator `~=` like this.

```
let didPhysicsGetA = aPlus ~= physics
print(didPhysicsGetA) // false
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
let physics = 76
let language = 98

let aPlus = 95...100

print(aPlus ~= physics) // false
print(aPlus ~= language) // true
```

OR

```
aPlus.contains(physics) // false
aPlus.contains(language) // true
```