# Simple way to express a +/- operation in swift

Tags: swift

Is there a simple way to express an operation that catches if a value is +/- a certain amount of another value? Or is the best way just a few < and > operators?

Like:

```
let a = 34

if a (+/-) 5 of 35 {
do this
} else { 
do this
}
```

I basically want some values to round to my custom input if they are +/- a small degree of another certain value.

Comment: Maybe this one `if (a-5...a+5).contains(35) {}`?

Comment: @CongNguyen `a-5...a+5 ~= 35`

Comment: if there is only one operation you can also use a ternary operator  `a-5...a+5 ~= 35 ? do this : do that`

Comment: Another way: `abs(target - actual) < 5`

Comment: @LeoDabus exactly the same with `contains`? I didn't know this before. Thanks :D

Comment: @CongNguyen yes it is called pattern match operator

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica There range approach expresses much clearly the intent (readability) IMO

Comment: Thank you gentleman! I especially like the simplicity :)

Comment: @LeoDabus I agree.

Comment: Related: [Can I use the range operator with if statement in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893110/can-i-use-the-range-operator-with-if-statement-in-swift)